# What is the type of an 'auto' return type when returning *this in an anonymous class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, auto

In this code:

```
struct
{
    auto operator[](const char*)
    {
        return *this;
    }

} m_some_class;
```

What is type of `auto` in here?

Comment: `Auto` tells the compiler to work out the return type based on the `return` statement.

Comment: `auto` is the type of the object, obviously.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> *What is type of `auto` in here ?*

The type is [`decltype(m_some_class)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) - I.e., the return value is of the same type as the variable `m_some_class`.

---

Note that the function will return a **copy** of `*this`.

If a reference to `*this` is wanted instead, you can use
`auto&` or, since C++14, the more generic [`decltype(auto)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

Comment: It's worth calling out explicitly: "This class has no identifier (name).  That's rare, but it happens. Lambdas also create classes without names, and officially `nullptr` has no named type"

Comment: @MooingDuck no named type, really? `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::nullptr_t,decltype(nullptr)>);` compiles fine, so `std::nullptr_t` is the named type of `nullptr`.

Comment: @MooingDuck The named type of `nullptr` (the `nullptr_t`) is `decltype(nullptr)` if I'm not mistaken.
@Ruslan: I think that's it's definition actually. It's backwards - I like that. :)

Comment: @Ruslan: If I recall, `nullptr` is a _keyword_, rather than an identifier (which you would otherwise have to have in a header). `nullptr_t` is a typedef of `decltype(nullptr)` defined in `<cstddef>` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr

Answer (score 18):

For anonymous structure types, internally the compiler creates a name and the auto in your case return the structure.

You can see below, that your anonymous structure is given name `__anon_1_1` and the `operator[]` function returns object of `__anon_1_1` structure. `m_some_class` is instance of type `__anon_1_1`

[cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/) website provides a way to understand

your code

```
struct
{
    auto operator[](const char*)
    {
        return *this;
    }

}m_some_class;
```

compiler version

```
struct __anon_1_1
{
  inline __anon_1_1 operator[](const char *)
  {
    return __anon_1_1(*this);
  }
  
  // inline constexpr __anon_1_1() noexcept = default;
  // inline constexpr __anon_1_1(const __anon_1_1 &) noexcept = default;
};

__anon_1_1 m_some_class = __anon_1_1();
```

Comment: It's far from clear that that is _actually_ the name used internally, as opposed to an artefact of the diagnostics (where _some_ name must be generated to avoid empty space in error messages). In practice there is little reason that it wouldn't be, but this is why we do not make assumptions and instead just code to standards (i.e. deem the type to have _no name_).

Answer (score 10):

The line in the given code:

```
return *this;
```

**returns the struct `m_some_class` itself**, i.e. the type of the `operator[]` is:

```
decltype(m_some_class); // i.e., the type returned is the same as the struct
```

Also, notice that this will only return a copy instance of the struct since the passed argument isn't given any reference-to operator. Any changes made to the copy of the struct won't affect the original struct.

---

### What's the `auto` keyword?

The `auto` keyword is typically used when the data type of something is unknown to the programmer, or it's too lengthy to type.

Also, the type defined by `auto` may vary depending upon the various situations. For instance:

```
auto len = vector.size(); // len is now defined as size_t in compile time
```

In some systems, the type of `len` may be `unsigned long`, and in my case, it's `unsigned long long`. Here, you can't explicitly define which qualifier to use correctly in this indeterminate place. Here we use the `auto` keyword.

Comment: The OP seems to be aware what the`auto` return mechanics are. The question is, what is the type for an *anonymous* class/struct. It is not possible to write that type by a programmer (except as Ted mentioned using `decltype`. (Also note that the type is not `m_some_class`, this is an object of the anonymous struct)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Now see. I've updated the answer after reading the reference.

Comment: @RohanBari Clearer! +1

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for that, also I just heard of `decltype()` but understood a few minutes ago the usage of it. Thanks for guiding me.

Comment: @RohanBari You are welcome. In this particular case, one could make a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias): `using foo_t = decltype(m_some_class);` and then claim that the function returns a `foo_t`. :-)

Answer (score 8):

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

#### TLDR: placeholder return type deduction

It is of no significance that the class is anonymous, as the return type is deduced solely from the `return` statement.

```
// Denote the type of the anonymous class as 'T'.

// Return type deduced to 'T'
auto operator[](const char*)
{
    return *this;
}

// Return type deduced to 'T&'
auto& operator[](const char*)
{
    return *this;
}

// Return type deduced to 'T&'
decltype(auto) operator[](const char*)
{
    return *this;
}
```

Details and relevant standard passages follows below.

---

### Placeholder return type deduction: `auto` (C++11 and onwards)

From [[expr.unary.op]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.unary.op#1) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> **[expr.unary.op]/1** The unary `*` operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which it is applied shall be **a pointer to an
> object type**, or a pointer to a function type **and the result is an
> lvalue referring to the object** or function to which the expression
> points. [...]

Thus, the result of `*this` is an lvalue referring to the object onto which the operator call is invoked.

From [[dcl.spec.auto]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#1) and [[dcl.spec.auto]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#2) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> **[dcl.spec.auto]/1** The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` *type-specifiers* are used to designate a placeholder type that **will be replaced later by deduction from an initializer.** [...]
>
> **[dcl.spec.auto]/2** The placeholder type can appear with a function declarator [...] in any context where such a declarator is
> valid. [...] **If the declared return type of the function contains a
> placeholder type, the return type of the function is deduced from
> non-discarded `return` statements** [...].

From [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct#2.1) and [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct#4) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> **[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/2** A type `T` containing a placeholder type, and a corresponding initializer `e`, are determined as follows:
>
> - (2.1) for a non-discarded `return` statement that occurs in a function declared with a return type that contains a placeholder type,
>   `T` is the declared return type and `e` is the operand of the return
>   statement. If the return statement has no operand, then `e` is
>   `void()`;
> - [...]
>
> **[dcl.spec.auto]/4** If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type `T'` replacing `T` **is determined using the rules
> for template argument deduction.** [...]
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> const auto &i = expr;
> ```
>
> The type of `i` is the deduced type of the parameter `u` in the call
> `f(expr)` of the following invented function template:
>
> ```
> template <class U> void f(const U& u);
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Thus, the return type of the member operator function

```
auto operator[](const char*)
{
    return *this;
}
```

of the anonymous type, say, `T`, is the deduced type of the parameter `u` in the call `f(*this)` of the following invented function template:

```
template <class U> void f(U u);
```

where, as per above, `*this` is an lvalue, and the return type is thus deduced as `T`; namely the type of the anonymous class.

Using the same argument, the return of the member operator function

```
auto& operator[](const char*)
{
    return *this;
}
```

of the anonymous type, say, `T`, is `T&`.

As per the argument above it is of no significance that the class is anonymous, as the return type is deduced solely from the `return` statement.

---

### Placeholder return type deduction: `decltype(auto)` (C++14 and onwards)

If we were to replace the placeholder return type `auto` with the placeholder type `decltype(auto)`, different rules governs how the return type is determined.

```
decltype(auto) operator[](const char*)
{
    return *this;
}
```

From [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct#5) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> If the placeholder is the `decltype(auto)` type-specifier, `T` shall be the placeholder alone. The type deduced for `T` is determined as described in [dcl.type.simple], **as though `e` had been the operand of the `decltype`**.

And, from [[dcl.type.simple]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4), [[dcl.type.simple]/4.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4.3) applies [extract]:

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as
> follows:
>
> - [...]
> - (4.4) otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;

as, per above, `e` (the return statement; `*this`) is a lvalue and neither [[dcl.type.simple]/4.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4.1), [[dcl.type.simple]/4.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4.2) nor [[dcl.type.simple]/4.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4.3) applies here.

Thus, the return type in the OP example modified using the `decltype(auto)` placeholder type is `T&`.

Answer (score 2):

It is `T`, where `T` is the unnamed type of the class.

Even though it has no known name, the type does still exist, and can be "used" via mechanisms such as `auto` and `decltype`.

You probably want `auto&`, though.